# Electric Field electrical charge

Tags: math, charge, field, field-strength

Hey i dont know how to solve this. Can somebody help me?

In the two-plate arrangement shown in the sketch, there is homogeneous electrical field strength
$$\vec{E_0} = -\vec{e}_y * 10\frac{kV}{cm}$$

[image]

Calculate the work done by the field when the charge Q = 1 μC from
Point P 1 (l, a, 0) is moved to point P 2 (0, 0, 0). Integrate once over for practice
the direct, sloping path and once over the square path along the
Coordinate axes.

This my try to solve this task ... But i dont know if it is right
$$ r = (-l\vec{e}_x -a\vec{e}_y) * t $$
$$ 0 <= t <= 1$$
$$ dr = (-l\vec{e}_x -a\vec{e}_y) * dt $$

$$ W = Q * \int_{0}^{1}\vec{E} dr$$

**UPDATE1**

$$ W = Q* E_0 * \int_{0}^{1} -\vec{e}_y* (-l\vec{e}_x - a\vec{e}_y)dt$$
$$ W = Q* E_0 * -\vec{e}y* (-l\vec{e}_x - a\vec{e}_y)$$
$$ W = Q* E_0 * a$$

Thanks to the answers. I think this is the solution.

Comment: Please post your answer as an answer, not an update to the question, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intuition: Work done by the field is Charge multiplied by the Potential Difference between the points. 
$$ W =Q.dV$$
Since a uniform vertical field is assumed, path taken by the charge between the plates is irrelevant. If the perpendicular distance is a,
$$dV = E_o .a$$
$$ ie, W = QE_o a$$

Comment: Charge path is irrelevant in any case \$W=Q\Delta V\$ ,no matter the field being uniform. The latter just helps working out \$\Delta V\$

Comment: Yes I mean in calculating dV from E :-)

Comment: Yes I am sure that's what you mean but I read _"Since a uniform vertical field is assumed, path taken by the charge between the plates is irrelevant."_  I am not native English speaker but it sounds different to me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks about right. Next step is to do the multiplication between \$\vec{E}\$ and \$d\vec{r}\$ keeping in mind that \$d \vec{r} \$ is also a vector. So this needs to be a vector product.

Sorry for not writing the symbols properly. <s>Apparently this site doesn't support latex math tags.</s>

Comment: This website does not have LaTeX. It has Mathjax which is similar to LaTeX. So if you want to use these symbols, your syntax has to be `\$ this \$` and it'll look like \$this\$. Otherwise, your commands for characters are the same for LaTeX syntax.

Comment: [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) might help.

Comment: i use double dollars. When you click edit you can look how i did this $$"xxx"$$

Comment: @RohatKılıç The Math SE has a slightly different way of initializing equations for Mathjax. On their website, it's `$ equation $` whereas, here, it's `\$ equation \$`. I don't know why it's different.

Comment: apparently engineers write costs often which means they use the $ sign frequently, so you can't use a single $ to trigger mathjax, it's escaped to \$